# How change a cell's background with an image in android

Tags: android, image, background, cell, tablelayout

I am new to android and doing an application with tableview.I am filling the table dynamically,meanwhile i also want to change the background of the cell according to my values.

For example,let's say that i have 4 values of brands(Nike,adidas,kappa,puma) when i read puma from file i want my cell for puma to be a picture that i assigned.Is there anyway to do it?

If i am not clear please leave a comment i will explain.

```
@Override
public void table_create(String[] brands) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    table_layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.score_table);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 82; i++) {

        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


            TextView tv = new TextView(this);

            tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,83));



            tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);






                    tv.setText(states[interest]);
                    putpic(states[interest]);

                    interest++;
                    break;





        row.addView(tv);



        table_layout.addView(row);

    }


}
```

This is my code to create table and put some text in every cell and works perfectly,with putpic method i want to change the background of the cell but i dont have that method :) this is the part that i need your help.I dont want an exact answer just give me a way to do it please.Thanks for your help

Comment: anyaways your using textview so why your not setting background image to textview as per your requirement using  tvObject.setImageResource(int resid) /setBackgroundResource() method

Comment: always welcome brother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do like this,

```
if(states[interest].toLowercase.contains("puma"))){
 tv.setBackground("puma image");
} else if(states[interest].toLowercase.contains("nike"))){
 tv.setBackground("nike image");
} else if(states[interest].toLowercase.contains("adidas"))){
 tv.setBackground("adidas image");
} else if(states[interest].toLowercase.contains("kappa"))){
 tv.setBackground("kappa image");
}
```

hope this may help you

Comment: using multiple if else statement increase processing speed i will suggest use switch statement which is more effective and more efficient than if else

Comment: if you agreed with my answer then can you accept it